# How to serve Files with Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-gis

In my django app I have a "Incidence" model that has several FileField and ImageField. I want to create an endpoint with Django Rest Framework to retrieve the information about an "Incidence" but what I have done so far only retrieves the url of the files. I need to return the files in a format that can be downloaded by the client application like binary data or other suggestion. How can I do it?
This is what I have done so far

Model Definition:

```
    class Incidence(BasicAuditModel):
    
        id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
        geom = models.PointField(verbose_name=_("Localización"), srid=4326, blank=True, null=True)
        name = models.CharField(_("Nombre"), max_length=255)
        incidence_type = models.CharField(_("Tipo incidente"), max_length=50, choices=INCIDENCE_TYPE_CHOICES, default="tipo1")
        description = models.TextField(_("Descripción"), blank=True, null=True)
        status = models.CharField(_("Status"), max_length=50, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default="creado")
        image1 = models.ImageField(verbose_name=_("Foto 1"), upload_to="incidencia_fotos",
                                                    null=False, blank=False)
        image2 = models.ImageField(verbose_name=_("Foto 2"), upload_to="incidencia_fotos",
                                                    null=False, blank=False)
        image3 = models.ImageField(verbose_name=_("Foto 3"), upload_to="incidencia_fotos",
                                                    null=False, blank=False)
        audio = models.FileField(verbose_name=_("Audio"), upload_to="incidencia_audioa",
                                                    null=False, blank=False)
        
        video = models.FileField(verbose_name=_("Video"), upload_to="incidencia_video",
                                                    null=False, blank=False)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
    
        class Meta:
            db_table = 'sini_incidence'
            managed = True
            verbose_name =  'Incidencia'
            verbose_name_plural =  'Incidencias'

class BasicAuditModel(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
                related_name="+",
                verbose_name=_("Creado por"), 
                null=True,
                blank=False,
                on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    modified_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
                    related_name="+",
                    verbose_name=_("Modificado por"), 
                    null=True,
                    blank=False,
                    on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name=_("Fecha creado"))
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name=_("Fecha modificado"))
```

Serializer class:

```
from rest_framework_gis.serializers import GeoFeatureModelSerializer
class IncidenceSerializer(GeoFeatureModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Incidence
        geo_field = "geom"
        fields = ('id','geom','name','incidence_type',
        'description','status', 'image1', 'image2', 'image3', 'audio', 'video')
        extra_kwargs = {'geom': {'required': True}} 
        read_only_fields = ['id','created_by', 'modified_by', 'created','modified']
```

This is the View:

```
class IncidenceAPIRetrieve(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Incidence.objects.all()
    serializer_class = IncidenceSerializer
```

This is the JSON i am getting. As you can see the endpoint returns the url to the files. I need to be able to download the files.

[image: Response image]